# development, staging, and production environments rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I'm creating an app that in addition to the live production environment requires a development and staging environment.  The production environment is currently live and on its own VPS instance.  A record:

```
myapp.com  1.2.3.4
```

The development and staging environments will be on their own VPS instance. I've configured the appropriate DNS records so each environment has its own sub-domain (A record in the myapp.com domain pointing to the dev/staging server:

```
dev.myapp.com 5.6.7.8
staging.myapp.com 5.6.7.8
```

The Nginx confix (Rails, Passenger) sets the root for each server (wild card SSL is configure in the http definition and port 80 redirects to port 443):

```
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name dev.myapp.com
   root /apps/myapp/dev/public
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name staging.myapp.com
   root /apps/myapp/staging/public
}
```

I'm a bit confused on the Rails side what else do I need to do to configure the environments so I can access the individual dev and staging environments by URL:

```
staging.myapp.com
dev.myapp.com
```

I know Capistrano allows you to set production and staging environments but I need both the dev and staging URLs to be live or should this be sufficient?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the environment for each instance using the [`rails_env`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#RailsEnv) option. For example:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name staging.myapp.com;
  root /apps/myapp/staging/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env staging;
}
```

Comment: this is key, otherwise they'll all use the `production` db by default, which you definitely don't want

Comment: Sweet, Thanks guys.  That worked. however, now I'm getting this ugly error in my error.log: client sent plain HTTP request to HTTPS port while reading client request headers, client

Comment: Nevemrind. I figured it out. Silly me. SSL was configured in http and not in each server instance because I don't have a wildcard or subdomain SSL Cert.